# Smarty. Use variable to compose Object key value

Tags: variables, smarty

I want to use smarty variable as the object key, but I can not make it working.

```
{$phrases['promote_no_{$type}_public_ready']}
```

`$phrases` is the array, and `$type` is string variable.
But it does not work as expected.

When I use

```
{$phrases['promote_no_iphone_public_ready']}
```

it works,

But

```
{$phrases['promote_no_{$type}_public_ready']}
```

with the `$type` assigned "iphone", does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All.

I have changed quote to double quote and it works.
So when I used following:

```
{$phrases["promote_no_{$type}_public_ready"]}
```

it works like charm.

Thank you.